# TinyMCE - Custom plugin makes visual editor blank in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to add [TinyMCE custom plugin](https://github.com/zotonic/zotonic/blame/bfce59c23f18065db7d1a53296a020472cb2e219/modules/mod_base/lib/js/modules/tinymce3.4.3.2/plugins/zbdo/editor_plugin.js) in wordpress that change the direction of selected text by using `<bdo>`. I register the plugin in wordpress:

```js
/*Register Custom TinyMCE plugin*/
add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'my_tinymce_plugins');

function my_tinymce_plugins() {
  $plugins_array = array(
    'tiny' => 'tiny.js' //Plugin directory is same as theme's funtion.php
  );
  return $plugins_array;
}
```

But it hide visual editor completely & also make text editor, un-editable. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overwriting all the other plugins, rather than just adding yours.  Try

```
function my_tinymce_plugins($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['tiny'] = 'tiny.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

instead.  You may need to prepend `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to `tiny.js` to ensure the URL is correct.

**Edit**

Further to your comment, here's some code I used a few years ago to add a button.  I can't say for certain best practices haven't changed, but it worked for me:

```
add_action('init', 'immo_add_column_button');
function immo_add_column_button() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'immo_add_column_tinymce_plugin');
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'immo_register_addcolumn_button');
    }
}

function immo_register_addcolumn_button($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "|", "addcol");
    return $buttons;
}

function immo_add_column_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['addcol'] = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/immo_column_button.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'immo_refresh_mce');
function immo_refresh_mce($ver) {
    // Force refresh of TinyMCE cache by updating the version number
    $ver += 3;
    return $ver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for answer. URI of tiny.js is correct but that code is not working. Visual Composer comes to normal but no button is not added to composer. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the `mce_buttons` filter as well?   `mce_external_plugins` adds the functionality, `mce_buttons` adds the button

Comment: yes ofcourse. And your code is not works with current version of tinyMCE :<